# Adding an error handling IF statement to my Open File code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code that works really well, when the user selects the correct workbook. However I'm trying to add some error handling to insert a MsgBox giving a warning if they select the wrong workbook. At the moment it just debugs with:

Run-time error 9 Subscript out of range:

```
Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a File")
If Fname = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set SrcWbk = Workbooks.Open(Fname)

    SrcWbk.Sheets("Results").Range("C7:AH43").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("RAW DATA").Range("A1")

SrcWbk.Close False
```

I've tried, but without success adding in the following code:

```
    If Right(Fname, 11).Value = "Results.xls" Then

            MsgBox "Please Select The Results Sheet", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub

        Else

    SrcWbk.Sheets("Results").Range("C7:AH43").Copy DestWbk.Sheets("RAW DATA").Range("A1")

SrcWbk.Close False

        End If
```

Comment: Can you clarify: *when the user selects the correct sheet*, do you mean you want the user to select a worksheet within a workbook, or does the user select a work**book** which you need to test if it holds the correct information?

Comment: If the issue you are facing has to do with testing if the filename contains "Results.xls" look into the `Instr(` function instead of `Right(`.

Comment: Have you debugged to see what value `Right(Fname, 11).Value` *is* returning?  "It doesn't work" isn't much to go on.  "It does this thing instead of that thing" is generally easier to solve

Comment: Hi All, apologies I appreciate my "It doesn't work" is a bit non-specific. I have updated the question with the error message.

Comment: Hi Plutian, just looking at the Instr function I'm not sure if that will work as Fname is the full file path and the character length will always vary.

Comment: It should be `If Right(Fname, 11) = "Results.xls" Then` i.e. `.Value` should not be there.

Comment: Thanks Shrivallabha! Thats got it working!

Comment: @Carlos80 The way you do it should be fine, but just to display my preference as well: `If InStr(1, Fname, "Results.xls", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then` would test the whole name string to contain the text "Results.xls", and negates the need to specify the string length. It will return 0 when not found, and any number above when found. So `> 0` will return `TRUE` when the correct workbook is selected.

Comment: Thanks Plutian, that makes a lot more sense now.